# Why is button not getting disabled using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, button

**Let me clear first that I checked other answers. They're either too old or not working for me...**

I am trying to dynamically disable and enable two navigation buttons using a function:

```
function arrowDisplayConfig() {
 
if (modeInSight == 1) {
    $("#rightArrow").prop("disabled",false);
    $("#leftArrow").prop("disabled",true);
}
if (modeInSight === maxModes) {
    $("#rightArrow").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#leftArrow").prop("disabled",false);
}
else {
    $("#rightArrow").prop("disabled",false);
    $("#leftArrow").prop("disabled",false);
 }
}
```

Basically disabling left arrow when its the first item in carousel and right one when its the last item, while keeping both enabled when in-between.

The problem is that this works perfectly for all cases except the first one. Don't know why.

P.S
I increase and decrease the modeInSight integer value in other functions and call this function after it.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd cases are exactly same. Please re-check and re-post your code. Also, the structure is wrong, this should be a IF-ELSEIF-ELSE or a SWITCH-CASE combination.

Comment: @skobaljic I rectified the code

Comment: @skobaljic is right - the structure is wrong.  You do an initial if, then immediately overwrite it in the if/else

Comment: @imposterSyndrome I didn't understood that at first. Got it now...used switch case...thank you both of you